# Knockout mapping plugin does not handle hierarchical data properly

Tags: memory-leaks, knockout.js, hierarchical-data, knockout-mapping-plugin

- I have hierarchical JSON structure that differs after every new JSON from the server side. Given my template, this does not adequately show model update.
  After troubleshooting, I noticed the mapping plugin does not correctly map child elements(or perhaps I am doing it incorrectly)
- I can also track the memory keeps growing for every update in the datamodel.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This simple test is up on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bru5a/1/

Here is my view

```
<div id="view">
The behavior is different depending on the order you load the model.
<a href="#" id="first">First</a>
<a href="#" id="second">Second</a>
<a href="#" id="third">Third</a>
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <div data-bind="if: $data.child">    
         <b data-bind="text: child.name"></b>
         <div data-bind="if: child.sub">
             <b data-bind="text: child.sub.name"></b>
         </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
var BaseModel = function(om) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(om, {}, this);
};
var resourceModel = null;
function applyJson(json) {
    try {
    if(resourceModel){
        ko.mapping.fromJS(json, {} ,resourceModel);
    } else {
        resourceModel = new BaseModel(json);
        ko.applyBindings(resourceModel, $("#view")[0]);
    }
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
function loadFirst() {
    var json = { "name" : "1",
                 "child" : {
                     "name": "Child One"
                 }
    };
    applyJson(json);
}
function loadSecond() {
     var json = { "name" : "2"  };
    applyJson(json);
}
function loadThird() {
     var json = { "name" : "3",
                 "child" : {
                     "name": "Child Three",
                    "sub" : {
                         "name" : "Third Sub Child"

                     }
                 }
    };
    applyJson(json);
}
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#second").click(function(){
            loadSecond();
            });
    $("#third").click(function(){
        loadThird();
        });
    $("#first").click(function(){
        loadFirst();
        });
    });​
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening in your case, is that knockout is behaving as designed.

To see what is happening, add the following line inside your outer div

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>
```

You can see what is being bound in your view model.

To understand what is being displayed, Watch what is happening the to the viewmodel as you select the different links.  As you update your model, you will see that once a property has been created, it remains there.  This is by design of how the mapper works.

Next, you have to remember that ko.applyBindings is only being called *ONE* time.  Therefore, the binding are only being applied one time to the properties that are in existence at the time the applyBindings is called.  When you add properties to your viewmodel later, they will not automatically be bound to the data-bindings.

To make this example work, you will need to re-think your view model so that all the properties are present at the time you call apply bindings.

---

**EDIT**
I've edited your fiddle to show what I was talking about at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/Bru5a/5/

Comment: Thanks for the response, somehow things don't add up. You are stating that "once a property has been created it remains there"

Comment: Check example 2 - http://jsfiddle.net/Bru5a/2/ and example 3 - http://jsfiddle.net/Bru5a/4/ . Now Click Third and First in both examples in two windows. You can see the results are not the same. I would like to point that my example 3 uses JSON Array and I have used Foreach clause.

Comment: In another excerise try First and third link. You can note that in example 3 new properties are automatically bound(which is contrary to "When you add properties to your viewmodel later, they will not automatically be bound to the data-bindings."). I am not entirely convinced this explanation is correct.

Comment: I should have saved my fiddle for my answer, but must have been too tired to do it at the time.  It's late for me, I'll put together a working example for you tomorrow or earlier Saturday morning.